# нужно ли делать слияние веток в локальном репозитории, если смерджил ветки удаленно через pull request

Tags: git

нужно ли делать слияние веток в локальном репозитории, если смерджил ветки удаленно через pull request? например, сделал push своей новой ветки с фичей, создал на удаленном репо пул реквест к ветке dev, мне смерджили, далее нужно ли мне сделать команду merge у сбея в локальном репо, или можно делать pull?

Comment: делать pull и всё

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет не нужно. Чтобы взять новое состояние удаленного репозитория тебе нужно просто сделать git pull